# Building a Date Range with only 1 date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

in Oracle I have a table like the below

ID, Acct, ParentID, StartTime, Address, City, State, Zip

This contains multiple rows for any given number of customer accounts . A row is entered by the App whenever a customer is created. A new row is created whenever a customer changes their address. So a customer can have only 1 row or N rows.

What i am looking to do is to create more useful reporting table that would include

ID, Acct, ParentID, StartTime, EndTime, Address, City, State, Zip

where any record that more than one row has an EndTime whenever the new address was created. A customer with only one record would be left with a NULL EndTime.

Thanks in advance

UPDATED WITH SOLUTION I DEVELOPED -- thanks for the input all here's what i came up with

```
select 
  ID           ,
  ACCOUNT_NO         ,
  PARENTID
  STARTTIME              ,
 MAX(mod_t)OVER( ORDER BY poid_id0 ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) as END_T,
  ADDRESS            ,
  CITY               ,
  FIRST_NAME         ,
  LAST_NAME          ,
  STATE              ,
  ZIP
```

Comment: How do you know that two rows represent the same customer account?  I'm assuming the Acct is the same, but is there anything else?

Comment: Stuart - yes, Acct is a unique alpha-numeric value

Comment: Thanks for the extra tags Raihan. Newbie, here. Really liking the community, hope to contribute in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT Adr.ID, Adr.Acct, X.FromDate, Adr.StartTime AS ToDate, Adr.Address, ...
FROM
    Adr INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(ID) AS ActualAdrID, MIN(StartTime) As FromDate FROM Adr GROUP BY Acct) X
        ON Adr.ID = X.ActualAdrID;
```

I group the addresses by account (I guess one acct is one customer) into X. I also assume that ID is the primary key that is incremented for each new record. X will hold the last ID of one customer and the first StartTime. The addresses are then joined to x, what means that only the last address for each cutomer is returned. Adr.StartTime is therefore the last StartTime. The first StartTime is taken from the subquery X.

---

EDIT:

```sql
SELECT
    A.ID,
    A.Acct,
    A.StartTime,
    (SELECT MIN(B.StartDate) FROM Adr B WHERE B.Acct=A.Acct AND B.ID>A.ID) AS EndDate,
    A.Address,
    ...
FROM Adr A;
```

Comment: I also would name the date in your table "Created" instead of "StartTime". This would be more comprehensive.

Comment: I wish i could have built the DDL Olivier, but this is an old dead app that i am trying to mine. Your query works well for delivering the most recent address, but unfortunately, what i'm trying to dig at is for what range was each Acct at any given address. In the app we are using now, we simply record the endDate on the Addr rows as we add new addrs. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: In this case I see no problem with the NULL EndDate, It just tells you that the address is still valid and therfore has no end date. If You don't like this NULL value then replace it with the actual date: `NVL(myDate,CURRENT_DATE)`. But your question is not very clear. In fact there is no question in your post at all. You only list some facts and let us guess what the question would be.

Comment: See my edit. The WHERE Condition could also be `WHERE B.Acct=A.Acct AND B.StartDate>A.StartDate`

Comment: Fair point about the lack of a Question. Duly noted. newbie, still learning the community, and greatly appreciate the efforts.

Comment: ah, the question  with the below sample rows would be looking for the output beneath

Comment: 1,A-1234, A-1, 1/1/1990, 1 Main Street, New York, NY, 10001  
2,A-1234, A-1, 2/1/1991, 15 State Street, Brooklyn, NY, 11001  

Result rows -- with EndDate inserted after StartDate  

1,A-1234, A-1, 1/1/1990, 2/1/1991, 1 Main Street, New York, NY, 10001  
2,A-1234, A-1, 2/1/1991, NULL, 15 State Street, Brooklyn, NY, 11001

Comment: Markdown in comments is very limited. You could add the example data to your question (edit the question). My second SQL-query should do, what your example data shows.

Comment: thanks Olivier. Sorted out higher performing method as well. I updated the question with what i ginned up OVER the last couple days. Thanks for all the input.